# joining elements in a list to an index and reset it on a new index value

Tags: python, pandas

I have a list:

```
['ww','xx','yy','zz']
```

and I have a df:

```
   val
A  2
A  3
A  3
A  4
B  5
B  4
```

I would like to join the list elements to the repeated index names and reset it on a new index name to generate the following output. Both index repeated values and elements in a list have the same len:

```
   val
Aww  2
Axx  3
Ayy  3
Azz  4
Bww  5
Bxx  4
```

How could I achieve this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This is one approach using `itertools.cycle`.

**Ex:**

```
from itertools import cycle

data = cycle(['ww','xx','yy','zz'])

df = pd.DataFrame({"val": [2,3,4,5,6,7,8,9], 'ind':["A","A","A","A","A","A","A","A"]})
df['ind'] = ["{}{}".format(i, next(data)) for i in df['ind']]    
df.set_index('ind', inplace=True)
print(df)
```

**Output:**

```
     val
ind     
Aww    2
Axx    3
Ayy    4
Azz    5
Aww    6
Axx    7
Ayy    8
Azz    9
```